# Что такое WEB API?

Tags: терминология

Я уже запутался и у меня куча вопросов:

1. Какое определение можно дать для WEB API и зачем он нужен ?
2. Можно ли сказать что если сервер на POST или GET запрос возвращет в ответ контент в формате JSON, то это у меня WEB API ?
3. Являются ли web-сервисами, например WCF, WEP API?

Comment: Можно даже если не в `JSON`. И если не только на `GET/POST`.

Comment: Да, так можно сказать. Я бы сказал, что web-api это если любой вид запроса по протоколу http возвращает машиночитаемый результат. т.е. результат который предназначен для программного разбора, а не чтения пользователем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Какое определение можно дать для WEB API и зачем он нужен?

Веб-API - это интерфейс прикладного программирования для веб-сервера или веб-браузера. Это концепция веб-разработки, обычно ограниченная клиентской стороной веб-приложения (включая любые используемые веб-фреймворки), и поэтому обычно не включает детали реализации веб-сервера или браузера, такие как SAPI или API, если они не доступны для общего доступа через удаленное веб-приложение.

Серверный веб-API - это программный интерфейс, состоящий из одной или нескольких общедоступных конечных точек для определенной системы сообщений запрос-ответ, обычно выраженной в JSON или XML, которая предоставляется через Интернет - чаще всего посредством HTTP веб сервера.

Гибридные приложения - это веб-приложения, сочетающие в себе использование нескольких серверных веб-API.

Веб-хуки - это серверные веб-API, которые принимают входные данные в виде универсального идентификатора ресурса (URI), который предназначен для использования в качестве удаленного именованного канала или типа обратного вызова, так что сервер действует как клиент для разыменования предоставленного URI и запуска событие на другом сервере, который обрабатывает это событие, тем самым обеспечивая тип однорангового IPC.

2. Можно ли сказать что если сервер на POST или GET запрос возвращет в ответ контент в формате JSON, то это у меня WEB API?

Да

3. Являются ли web-сервисами, например WCF, WEP API?

WCF и ASP.NET Web API - это фреймворк/библиотека с помощью которой вы можете организовать работу WEB-API в вашем приложении.

Answer (score -4):

1. Web Api - платформа для создания HTTP служб, таких как REST и SOAP(но она более пригодна для Rest, чем для SOAP)
2. Нет. Web Api просто платформа для создания служб. Если запрос работает с форматом JSON, о скорее всего(не обязательно), служба запросов построена на REST. Если же возвращает XML, то скорее всего на SOAP.
3. Нет. WCF и Web Api разные вещи. Чтобы много не писать, оставлю [ссылку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Кажется, вы путаете Web Api и ASP.NET Web Api. Возможно, автор вопроса тоже их путает, но это не делает ответ верным.